# How does one cook with aloe?

Tags: vegetables

There is an asian grocery nearby and I've seen foot long lengths of aloe vera plant in the produce section.  I have an aloe plant at home. What do you suppose people do with aloe as a ingredient?

Comment: Just beware that not all aloe species are edible and please do some research on side-effects and safe quantities.

Comment: From [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aloe_vera#Toxicity): "Under the guidelines of California Proposition 65, orally ingested non-decolorized aloe vera leaf extract has been listed by the OEHHA, along with goldenseal, among chemicals known to the state to cause cancer or reproductive toxicity... IARC studies have found ingested non-decolorized liquid aloe vera to be carcinogenic in animals, and state that it is a possible carcinogen in humans as well.

Answer (score 4):

As Kruti Jani rightly pointed out, you can make aloe vera juice. Aloe vera gel ([made like this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CPjUHfQheX4)) can also be diced finely and mixed into fruit juices to give a texture and slight freshness to a glass of juice. I have also seen it (the aloe vera gel) mixed with lemongrass jelly or mango sago dessert.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.clovegarden.com/ingred/li_aloez.html) may be a good starting point

- use a peeler to remove the "latex", the tough skin on the leaf to get to the translucent "gel" inside
- cut gel into small pieces, be sure to get rid of all that is not colourless
- boil gel pieces in water for a 1-5 minutes

Please check if your plant is one of the edible species.

Comment: Please include the main relevant points here. It's easier on our readers to have mostly self-contained answers, and it mitigates the consequences if the link breaks (which happens an awful lot over time).

Answer (score -1):

you can make aloe vera juice from it.